# Are Muslims allowed to pray for Kafirs?

Tags: dua, kuffar, kufr, surat-al-kafirun

I'm curious about Islam, this is one question that's is not clear for me, based on what I read.

Comment: It's not even clear for muslims themselves. Many say yes, others say yes, but only for you to be guided the right way. And others say no.

Comment: Could you let us know what you have read?

Comment: Just the Quran http://quran.com/ , and saw some videos on youtube about it.

I haven't read the whole Quran, I've been cherry picking parts that look like they may have answers for the questions I have.


About the youtube videos, they seem to be only about very strident and fundamentalist imans, so I don't know if they paint a faithful picture.

Answer (score 1):

Scholars have given different answers to different issues when it comes to praying or making dua' (supplication) for a non-Muslim: Making difference in the cause, intent or goal of the prayer, whether the non-Muslim is alive or not and finally about his attitude towards Muslims and Islam.

Generally one could say:

- It's not allowed to pray for (forgiveness for) a non-Muslim who is dead and died as a disbeliever!

  > "There is no difference of opinion among the scholars that one cannot pray for forgiveness and mercy for a kaafir who died in a state of kufr."

Some details for non-Muslims who are alive:

- It is allowed to pray for the guidance of a non-Believer, if one expects him to convert to Islam!
- The most common view is that it is allowed to pray for a non-Muslim asking Allah to have mercy on him (but there's no consensus among scholars about this Issue)

> "in the sense that Allah may bestow mercy upon him by saving him from
>   sin and guiding him to obedience, and thus transferring him from being
>   one of those who are subject to His wrath to being one of those upon
>   whom He bestows His mercy".

As evidences for that see for example the Verse ([14:36](http://legacy.quran.com/14/36)) and in the Sunah in Jami' [at-Thirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/729520) and Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/266)).

- But in general it is not allowed to ask for forgiveness and mercy for non-Muslims because of the Verses ([9:113-114](http://legacy.quran.com/9/113-114)).
- It is allowed to do supplication for a non-Muslim asking Allah to heal him from a disease or wealth or anything which we may want in this life! **Unless** this non-Muslim is hostile to Muslims! As Scholars toke the hadith about the rights of Neighbors as an evidence (see for example [here](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/46))

Here are a few related References:
- A Fatwa on [praying for forgiveness and mercy for a kaafir](https://islamqa.info/en/153574)
- A Fatwa on [praying for guidance for a kaafir](https://islamqa.info/en/43164)
- A Fatwa in Arabic on [what kind of supplication or prayer is allowed (can a Muslim perform) for a non-Believer](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=14165)
- A Fatwa on [the rights of non-Muslim Neighbors towards a Muslim](https://islamqa.info/en/131777)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Do you know if there is any difference between a Kaafir and a Dhimmi in this regard?

Comment: No it's the same some of my references are refering to dhimi rules while others talk about kufar